What does 身の上 mean here?
From Oshi no ko ch. 145,

This kid seems to be making a business arrangement on behalf of his agency.
I am uncertain what he might mean by 子供の身の上. Perhaps, it is something like "while we are kids"?

身の上 means condition which (someone) is in. It can be any condition, but Xの身の上である is often used in the context where the person is in a miserable (or generally non-desirable) condition of being X. For example, 捕虜の身の上 = the miserable condition of being a captive.
In the sentence, it is ok to think it means while we are kids. To be more precise, using 身の上 (instead of 我々(は)子供ではありますが) adds something like we are just (powerless) kids.

In this case I think it is better understood as a humble wording in business settings. The whole line is in such an unbelievably adultly style.
